# Select related and prefetch related for multiple reverse foreign keys with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently having issues accessing values in a queryset. I have a models.py for my app that is set up like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=250)

class Patient(models.Model):

        status_choices = [
        ('A', 'Current Admission'),
        ('D', 'Discharged'),
        ('U', 'Unknown'),
    ]

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    patient_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=status_choices,
        null=True, default='U',
        verbose_name='Patient Status'
    )
    related_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patients')

class PatientStay(models.Model):
    admit_date = models.DateField()
    projected_dc_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stay_to_patient_relationship = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stays')
    
class PatientLOC(models.Model):
    loc_to_stay_relation = models.ForeignKey(PatientStay, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='locs')
    level_of_care = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    loc_start = models.DateField(null=True)
    loc_end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I am trying to do is query this to get (for a particular company) the patients, their related stay (filtered for only active), and their related PatientLOC.

A result like this:

- Company:
- -Patient
- --Stay
- ---LOC's
- -Patient
- --Stay
- ---LOC's
- -Patient
- --Stay
- ---LOC's

I have come up with this (less the filtering):

```
company = Company.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('patients__stays', 'patients__stays__locs').get(id=2)
```

Which I can loop through and get the patient and the stays, but I cannot seem to get to the LOC's for those patients. So, I can do something like this:

```
company = Company.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('patients__stays', 'patients__stays__locs').get(id=2)

patients = company.patients.all()

for patient in patients:
    ...:     print(patient)
    ...:     print(patient.stays.all())
```

But something like this will not work:

```
company = Company.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('patients__stays', 'patients__stays__locs').get(id=2)
patients = company.patients.all()

for patient in patients:
     ...:     print(patient)
     ...:     for stay in patient.stays.all():
     ...:         print(stay)
     ...:         for loc in patient.stays.locs.all():
     ...:             print(loc)
```

Outside of the fact I am using a bunch of nested for loops, what is the best way to do this? Is there a way to just loop over the patients like this in psuedocode:

```
for patient in patients:
    print(patient)
    print(patient.stay)
    print(patient.stay.loc)
```

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I'm out of guesses. The documentation led me to the select_related and prefetch_related (which I'm sure I am using incorrectly in some way).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: FYI: `select_related` isn't doing anything for you here.  Prefetch related just saves a database trip.  If you don't care about queries, then the only problem with your nested for loops code was the line `for loc in patient.stays.locs.all()` - that would be `for loc in stay.locs.all()` - you were almost there!

Answer (score 2):

You can nest prefetch calls:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
patients = Patient.objects.filter(company__id=2).prefetch_related(
   Prefetch(
      'stays',
      queryset=PatientStay.objects.prefetch_related('locs')
   ))

for patient in patients:
   print(patient)
   print([stay for stay in patient.stays.all()])
   print([loc for stay in patient.stays.all() for loc in stay.locs.all()])
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for the nested prefetch call information. How can I access this from a template? I cannot (well, at least that I can see) use list  comprehensions in the templates nor will anything like for stay in patient.stay.filter(is_active=True). Do I need to somehow do these operations in my view function and then save them > pass as context that way? I'm on the struggle bus with this one.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to loop through it, but I just had to do it without comprehensions and use the Django filters rather than the queryset filters.